# Error when setting icon with CX Freeze

Tags: python, build-process, cx-freeze

I keep getting this error when I add the icon arugment to my script:

> setRelativeReferencePaths()
>   install_name_tool: input file: build/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/logo.ico is not a Mach-O file
>   prepare_qt_app()

The Icon is a .ico and i have converted it from a PNG however it always comes up with this error.

What does this error mean and how can I get around it?

My script looks like:

```
setup(
    name = application_title,
    version = "0.1",
    description = "application description...",
    options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
    executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base, icon="./resources/logo.ico")])
```

I get the same error with an ICNS file as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's answered in the [cx_freeze mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29087165):

> I had to track down and copy qt_menu.nib into the Resources directory of the application, and create a blank qt.conf file, also in the Resources directory.